# where can I find a revised and updated demo/tut for something like Rails3.1.2 "polling-for-changes"

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, polling, ruby-on-rails-3.2

where can I find a revised and updated demo/tut for something like Rails3.1.2 "polling-for-changes" like this great but not updated screencasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes?view=asciicast ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling is 2010. You should look into websockets instead. I suggest [socket.io](http://socket.io), which will automatically degrade to Long-Polling if necessary.

Comment: but socket.io is not supported from all browser, or I'm wrong?
(thank you(

Comment: websockets aren't supported by all browsers, but it degrades nicely [http://socket.io/#browser-support](http://socket.io/#browser-support)

Comment: yeah, it's a lot less management on your part. Just write the code and the library will pick the fastest and most-reliable protocol

Answer (score 0):

I built a gem for what you need. Instead of client polling, the server should push data to connected clients as it becomes available.

Check out [Entangled](https://github.com/dchacke/entangled) - it does just that for a Rails back end and an Angular front end.

Answer (score -2):

You can't really move from polling if you plan to stay in ruby on rails land.

Other solutions, like socket.io, implies you move to an evented platform, like node.js or eventmachine.
If you mix frameworks and languages, you'll get an application which will be harder to maintain and to deploy. So I think it's not a good plan.

I think that http://pusher.com/ should solve all of your problems.

General note:
In 2012 you should not render HTML server side, but you should pass JSONs to your client, and then you render them with mustache or handlebars.

If the data you are polling are public, you can use HTTP cache to improve the performance.

Comment: In 2015, Rails is very much capable of evented programming. Check out [Tubesock](https://github.com/ngauthier/tubesock) and [Entangled](https://github.com/dchacke/entangled).